# Moving to previous form

Tags: c#

I'm trying to move back to the previous form with the information I filled out on it, but when i click the previous button it just generates a new previous form. Heres my code for both next and previous. Is there any way to move back to a previous form with the information I put in already without generating a new previous form? thanks.

```
//moves to next form
    public void next()
    {
        Form3 f4 = new Form3();
        f4.Show(this);
        Hide();
    }

    //Moves to previous form
    public void Back()
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.Show(this);
        Hide();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** You are creating new instance of `Form1` in Back() method so eachtime it creates a New `Form1` instance in memory and displays the same to you rather than displaying the existing Form1 which hasbeen filled with values (already hidden) by taking it from memory.

**Solution:** You can use `Application.OpenForms[]` to get the required Form which is already available in memory.

Try This:

```
//Moves to previous form
public void Back()
{
  Form myform = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"]; 
  myform.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ou could show form f4 using ShowDialog() instead of Show(). This would bring execution back to form f1 after form f2 has closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
In Form2 :
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    formRegistration.ShowDialog();
    // We get here when formRegistration's DialogResult gets set
    this.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Sudhakar.
Alternative:

```
public void next()
{
    Form3 f4 = new Form3(this);
    this.Hide();
    f1.BringToFront();        
    f4.Show();

}
public void Back()
{
    Form1 f1 = new Form1(this);
                this.Hide();
                f1.BringToFront();
                f1.Show();
}
```

Also, add something into all your form class and constructors:

```
Form storedPrev;

public Form1(Form prev)
{
    this.storedPrev = prev;
}
```

In your form closing event handler, add this code:

```
storedPrev.Show();
```